# AVFoundation Framework and Mediaplyer Framework: Which is the best framework to play audio/video in iOS Application?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, media-player

I am new to iOS. I need to implement both video and audio player in my app. So  please advice me which player is most suitable as per developer point of view.

Choice:

- AVplayer (AVFoundation )
- MPMovieplayerController(MediaPlayer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `AVPlayer` since `MPMovieplayerController` is deprecated.

Comment: So what is different between a AVKit Framework and AVFoundation Framework ??

Comment: @MrDipuna AVKit is an higher level framework which allows you to play movies, AVFoundation manages the assets only. If my answer resolved your doubt please mark my answer as right, I would appreciate it thanks

Answer (score 3):

The MPMoviePlayerViewController class is formally deprecated in iOS 9. (The MPMoviePlayerController class is also formally deprecated.) To play video content in iOS 9 and later, instead use the AVPictureInPictureController or AVPlayerViewController class from the AVKit framework, or the WKWebView class from WebKit.

So Better use AVPlayer.